# Bulk SMTP email verification without getting IPs blocked or SMTP requests rejected?

Tags: python, email, smtp, email-validation

I was trying to bulk verify email-addresses and soon enough my requests got rejected and later my IP was blocked. After which I came to the question how does services like snov.io, hunter.io, zerobounce.net, etc., verify email-addresses in bulk without getting their IP's blocked or requests getting rejected (I have been experimenting in python).

From my research (till now) there is no other method than sending helo and rcpt request and wait for the results, confirmation from the SMTP server.

Essentially, I want to ask how these services verify these email-addresses in bulk (more 10's of thousands) and do not face the same issue as I am facing.